# rtcore64.sys in use - process explorer does not show why

Tags: windows-10, process-explorer

I am trying to install new version of MSI AterBurner. First it said application is active, so installation will cancel. OK so after I closed the application I started setup again and I got
[image]

I tried searching via Process Explorer what is holding that file but it does not find anything even when it's running as admin! So two questions: what is holding that file and why can't process explorer find it? Shouldn't it search for all open handles?

Comment: Remove the current version, then reboot, that should take care of any open file handles